# Sort date in PowerShell that has data type String and format 'MM/yyyy' and 'dd/MM/yyyy'

Tags: powershell, sorting, date, datetime, hashtable

I have hashtable with dates (hahstable key, stored as a string) and numbers of users created on these dates.
I want to sort hashtable based on date (by date and by month)

When I sort hashatable by key it gives the result:

```
19/03/2023
31/03/2023                     
31/05/2023                     
31/08/2022                     
31/10/2022                     
31/12/2022
```

So basically sorting happend for string data structure, not for the date.

Right way to sort by date it would be:

```
31/10/2022                     
31/12/2022
19/03/2023
31/03/2023                     
31/05/2023                     
31/08/2022
```

How to sort it the right way considering that date is stored as a string and has at the end to be stored as a string too.

I need the same sorting but for the date with format MM/yyyy

Wrong:

```
10/01/2023
10/05/2023
15/12/2022
14/11/2022
23/02/2023
```

Right:

```
14/11/2022
15/12/2022
23/02/2023
10/01/2023
10/05/2023
```

Thank you!

I tried to sort this way:

```
$hashtable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property:Key
```

But it sorts date as string, not as a date.

I tried to convert string to date and back, but it doesn't work for situations when I need to sort by months or years.

Comment: You need to convert the date string into a DateTime object. Why not add the dates as objects in the hashtable?

Comment: @vonPryz, that won't work as a hash tables are unordered by nature. To do that you will need something like a [sorted dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2).

Comment: @iRon I am aware of that. Should the hashtable keys be datetimes, piping GetEnumerator() to sort-object will sort dates properly. That would be more simple and locale-independent too.

Comment: Your `MM/yyyy` example is broken: the strings are three part, and `23/02/2023` appears before `10/01/2023` in `right`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$HashTable =  @{
    '10/01/2023' = 1
    '10/05/2023' = 2
    '15/12/2022' = 3
    '14/11/2022' = 4
    '23/02/2023' = 5
}

$HashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { [DateTime]::Parse($_.Key, (Get-Culture nn-NO)) }
# Or: ... | Sort-Object { [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Key, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $Null) }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
14/11/2022                     4
15/12/2022                     3
10/01/2023                     1
23/02/2023                     5
10/05/2023                     2
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
$hashtable = @{}
$hashtable.add( '19/03/2023', 1 )
$hashtable.add( '31/03/2023', 2 )
$hashtable.add( '31/05/2023', 3 )
$hashtable.add( '31/08/2022', 4 )
$hashtable.add( '31/10/2022', 5 )
$hashtable.add( '31/12/2022', 6 )

$hashtable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object {$_.name -as [datetime]}
```

Comment: That will only work if your current culture uses the required `'dd/MM/yyyy'` format

Answer (score 0):

Using the [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties#sort-object), you can sort data in different orders per property:

```
$hashtable = @{}
@'
19/03/2023
31/03/2023
12/05/2023
31/08/2022
31/10/2022
31/12/2022
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    ForEach-Object {
        $hashtable.Add(
            $_, (Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 10))
    }

$hashtable.GetEnumerator() |
  Sort-Object -Property @{expr={
    [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Key, @('dd/MM/yyyy'), $null)}}
```

> ```
> Name                           Value                                           
> ----                           -----                                           
> 31/08/2022                     0                                               
> 31/10/2022                     2                                               
> 31/12/2022                     8                                               
> 19/03/2023                     3                                               
> 31/03/2023                     3                                               
> 12/05/2023                     1
> ```

**Note**: you can apply another overload for the [`ParseExact` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact).